# How can I use a “for” loop to find the first 3 perfect numbers after 28?

Tags: java, math

How can I use a “for” loop to find the first 3 perfect numbers after 28? 
Here is some code I'm using.

I can't seem to get anything past 2 numbers. If I try to increase i<= 2000000000 it tells me the integer is to large.

```
public class JBaneling
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("3 nearest Perfect numbers after 29 ");

        for (int i = 29; i <= 2000000000; i++) {
            test1(i);
        }
    }



    public static void test1(int number)
    {
        int sum = 0;

        for(int divisor=1; divisor < number; divisor++)
        {
            if ((number % divisor) ==0)
            {
                sum = sum + divisor;
            }
        }

        if(sum==number)
        {
            System.out.println(number + " is a perfect number");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can break the loop once sum > number.  If you start the loop in test1() at the number-1 and go down to 1, you may trip this condition sooner.

Comment: You should use `Integer.MAX_INT` in the loop check, this makes your intent clearer.

Comment: You can also do the loop in test1() from 1 to the square root of `number`.  When you add `divisor` to `sum`, also add `number/divisor`; its evil twin.  The only exception is that you should include 1 in `sum`, but not `number`.  So initialize `sum` to 1 and let the loop in test1() start at 2.

Comment: If you're allowed to use Euclid's theorem on perfect numbers, your quest will become much simpler.

Comment: Instead of `sum = sum + divisor`, try `sum += divisor`.

Comment: @Marko Technically, you'd still have to check all the odd numbers, because noone has been able to prove the nonexistance of odd perfect numbers. But even then you could make things a lot more efficient by factoring the numbers instead of testing every possible divisor.

Comment: @gobern What does that have to do with anything? Besides, it's just a stylistic choice.

Comment: @Antimony Since it has (obviously) been proven for every single odd integer from zero to (insert a minbogglingly large integer here) that it is not perfect, we can rely on that fact, too :)

Comment: @antimony Yes, just a stylistic choice, but I think it's a convenient feature that he may not be aware of.

Comment: @gobernador Not worth starting to enumerate all the things he's not aware of :)

Comment: @Antimony, the OP asked the same question and I argued and unless using Euclid's formula it'd be just unreasonable to try each number. It's a mathematics question after all. Imagine trying to find the highest square number in the Fibonacci sequence relying on brute force.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just taking a long time to compute the third perfect number. After `8128` the next perfect number is `33550336`. Now consider that your code is testing **every** integer between `8128 ... 33550336`, by computing **each** divisor of each of those integers.

Also consider that this next perfect number, `33550336` is the largest perfect number that you'll be able to represent with a java `int`: `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is (2^31 - 1). You'll get a *few* more with a `long` - `Long.MAX_VALUE` is (2^63 - 1) - but you'll be waiting a **long** time for that 8th perfect number.

Note that you only need to consider divisors up to the square root of `number`, then find their matching divisor above the square root, but even so you'll still need to wait a really long time before getting to the next perfect number.

Comment: Is it possible to shorten it down so it doesn't take so long?

Comment: @user1493667 As I said, make use of Euclid's thoerem. Wikipedia has all the info on it. It's really dead simple. For example, check out this line of code: `for (int i : new int[]{5, 7, 13}) System.out.println( (1<<(i-1))* ((1<<i)-1));`

Comment: @Marko Don't forget to check for odd perfect numbers!

Comment: @Antimony I rise on the shoulders of giants who cheked them before me and didn't find any :)

Comment: @Marko, if you're going to do that, you might as well just hardcode the answers. It's simpler anyway.

Comment: @Antimony I had exactly this discussion with another contributor at the OP's first instance of this same question, and that was **my** argument there. Right now I am guessing at what the teacher might be happy with, and a solution based on Euclid's seems a fine candidate. If using only the definition of a perfect number and wanting a solution that will find that third number today, it' going to be a hell of a complicated solution, with all kinds of optimizations.

Comment: @Marko I agree that for a homework assignment, it's best to ask the teacher, and for this kind of assignment, the teacher is probably fine with Euclid's formula.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure the code actually terminated? I don't see anything wrong with the actual calculations, but it is hideously inefficient, so if you are getting only 2 numbers, that's probably because you stopped the program before it ever got to the third number. In case you were wondering, it is 33550336, which is well under the loop limit you set.

Comment: Is it possible to break it then to continue at a higher number?

Comment: Yes. You just have to make it store its progress periodically and then continue from that point. But that's complicated to do. You're much better off just making your algorithm efficient in the first place. I'd recommend reading about perfect numbers and number theory on Wikipedia.